# Trouble Fetching Details with AngularJS Service After Selecting Item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, http, service

I'm working on an AngularJS application and have encountered an issue where selecting an item from a list using one service (`testPanelService`) correctly logs the selected item's details, but when trying to fetch related details using another service (`panelInvestigationService`), I don't receive the expected data.

Here is the service file:

```
export interface IPanelInvestigation extends IAggregateRoot<string> {
    investigationId: string;
    testName: string;
    sampleName: string;
    testPanelId: string;
    testPanelName: string;
    testParameters: ITestParameter[];
    retired: boolean;
  }
  
export  interface ITestParameter extends IAggregateRoot<string> {
  testParameterId: string;
  name: string;
}

export interface IPanelInvestigationService
  extends IAggregateRootService<IPanelInvestigation, string> {
  query(
    text?: string,
    page?: IPageRequest
  ): ng.IPromise<IPageReponse<IPanelInvestigation>>;
}

interface IPanelInvestigationResource
  extends IResourceService<IPanelInvestigation> {
  fetch: ng.resource.IResourceMethod<IPageReponse<IPanelInvestigation>>;
}

export class PanelInvestigationService
  extends EntityService<IPanelInvestigation, string, IPanelInvestigationResource>
  implements IPanelInvestigationService
{
  static $inject = ['PanelInvestigationResource'];
  constructor(private resource: IPanelInvestigationResource) {
    super(resource);
  }

  query = (
    text?: string,
    page?: IPageRequest
  ): ng.IPromise<IPageReponse<IPanelInvestigation>> => {
    if (angular.isUndefined(page)) {
      page = {
        page: 0,
        size: 32000,
      };
    }
    return this.getResource().fetch({
      text: text,
      page: page.page,
      size: page.size,
      sort: page.sort,
    }).$promise;
  };
}

export class PanelInvestigationResourceService {
  private apiRoot: string = Settings.serverResource('api/get-individual-investigations-by-set/:investigationSetId/');
  constructor(private $http) {}

  query = (id: string) => this.$http.get(`${this.apiRoot}${id}`);

  fetch = (id: string) => this.$http.get(`${this.apiRoot}${id}`);

  get = (id: string) =>
    this.$http.get(`${this.apiRoot}${id}`).success(function (data) {
      if (data) {
        data = angular.fromJson(data);
      }
      return data;
    });

  update = (id: string) => this.$http.put(`${this.apiRoot}${id}`);
}

PanelInvestigationResource.$inject = ['$resource'];

export function PanelInvestigationResource(
  $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService
): IPanelInvestigationResource {
  const resourceUrl = Settings.serverResource(
    'api/get-all-test-panels/:investigationSetId/'
  );

  return <IPanelInvestigationResource>$resource(
    resourceUrl,
    {},
    {
      query: { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
      fetch: { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
      get: {
        method: 'GET',
        transformResponse: function (data) {
          if (data) {
            data = angular.fromJson(data);
          }
          return data;
        },
      },
      update: { method: 'PUT' },
    }
  );
}
```

Here is the relevant part of my TypeScript controller:

```
      $onInit = () => {
        this.loadTestPanels();
      };
  
      loadTestPanels = () => {
        this.testPanelService.query().then((response) => {
          console.log('TestPanelService response:', response.content);
          this.dataSet = response.content;
          // Optionally, load panel investigations here or based on a user action
        });
      };
  
      loadPanelInvestigations = (testPanelId) => {
        this.panelInvestigationService.query(testPanelId).then((response) => {
          
          this.dataSet = response.content.map(investigation => ({
            code: investigation.investigationId, // Adjust according to actual data
            name: investigation.testName // Adjust according to actual data
          }));
        });
        // Log to check if dataSet is populated correctly
        console.log('Updated dataSet with panel investigations:', this.dataSet);
  
      };
  
      onSelected = (item) => {
        console.log('Selected item:', item);
        this.loadPanelInvestigations(item.code);
        this.rootScope.$broadcast('MrsPatientInvestigationSelectSetController', {
          data: item,
        });
      };
    },
```

and html:

```
<div class="investigation-select-container">
  <table datatable="ng"  class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="i in vm.dataSet">
        <td>{{ i.code }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="vm.onSelected(i)">
           Choose me
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

When I select an item, I get the following output, which corresponds to the result from testPanelService: Selected item: {code: '02', name: 'Pregnancy', retired: false, ...}
However, when trying to fetch details with panelInvestigationService.query(testPanelId), I expect to receive an array of investigation details as shown below:

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "investigationId": "9b26f140-b023-11e8-9321-a0d37a41e1b4",
      "testName": "Full Blood Test",
      "sampleName": "Blood",
      "testPanelId": "01",
      "testPanelName": "Diabetic",
      "testParameters": [
        {
          "testParameterId": "100",
          "name": "White Blood Count"
        },
        // ... other parameters
      ],
      "retired": false
    }
    // ... potentially other investigations
  ],
  // ... other response metadata
}
```

But I do not see the expected output in the console after panelInvestigationService.query() is called. The selection log works fine, but the follow-up data fetch does not seem to behave as intended.

What I've tried so far:

Confirmed that testPanelId is correctly passed to panelInvestigationService.query().
Checked the network request in the browser's developer tools, and the request is made with the correct testPanelId.
Added console logs to verify the structure of the response from panelInvestigationService.query().
I'm not sure why the panelInvestigationService.query() isn't returning the expected data. Could there be an issue with the way I'm handling the promise or updating the dataSet? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in the service, especially. so i adjusted it to look like this:

```
export interface ITestPanelInvestigationService
  extends IAggregateRootService<ILaboratoryTest, string> {
  queryByInvestigationSetId(
    investigationSetId?: string, //this is the itestpanel code
    page?: IPageRequest
  ): ng.IPromise<IPageReponse<ILaboratoryTest>>;
}

interface ITestPanelInvestigationResource
  extends IResourceService<ILaboratoryTest> {
  fetch: ng.resource.IResourceMethod<IPageReponse<ILaboratoryTest>>;
  queryByInvestigationSetId: ng.resource.IResourceMethod<IPageReponse<ILaboratoryTest>>;
}

export class TestPanelInvestigationService
  extends EntityService<ILaboratoryTest, string, ITestPanelInvestigationResource>
  implements ITestPanelInvestigationService
{
  static $inject = ['TestPanelInvestigationResource'];
  constructor(private resource: ITestPanelInvestigationResource) {
    super(resource);
  }
//CORRECTLY NAMED THIS QUERY
  queryByInvestigationSetId(investigationSetId?: string, page?: IPageRequest): ng.IPromise<IPageReponse<ILaboratoryTest>> {
    // Default page request if not provided
    if (angular.isUndefined(page)) {
      page = { page: 0, size: 32000 };
    }
    return this.getResource().queryByInvestigationSetId({
      investigationSetId: investigationSetId,
      page: page.page,
      size: page.size,
      sort: page.sort,
    }).$promise.catch(error => {
      console.error('Error querying investigation set ID:', error);
      throw error; // Rethrow after logging or handle accordingly
    });
  };
//USED THE CODE HERE AGAIN
  ITestPanel = (code: string): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    return this.getResource().fetch({ id: code})
      .$promise;
  };
}

export class TestPanelInvestigationResourceService {
  private apiRoot: string = Settings.serverResource('api/get-individual-investigations-by-set/');
  constructor(private $http) {}
  
//AND ADDED THE RESPECTIVE METHOD HERE WITH THE PROPER SYNTAX FOR THE 'ID'
  queryByInvestigationSetId = (investigationSetId: string) => {
    this.$http.get(
      Settings.serverResource(`api/get-individual-investigations-by-set/${investigationSetId}`)
    );
  };
  fetch = (id: string) => this.$http.get(`${this.apiRoot}${id}`);

  get = (id: string) =>
    this.$http.get(`${this.apiRoot}${id}`).success(function (data) {
      if (data) {
        data = angular.fromJson(data);
      }
      return data;
    });

  update = (id: string) => this.$http.put(`${this.apiRoot}${id}`);
}

TestPanelInvestigationResource.$inject = ['$resource'];

export function TestPanelInvestigationResource(
  $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService
): ITestPanelInvestigationResource {
  const resourceUrl = Settings.serverResource(
    'api/get-all-test-panels/:investigationSetId'
  );

  return <ITestPanelInvestigationResource>$resource(
    resourceUrl,
    {},
    {
      query: { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
      fetch: { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
      queryByInvestigationSetId: {
        method:'GET',
        url: Settings.serverResource('api/get-all-test-panels/:investigationSetId',),
        isArray: false,
      },
      get: {
        method: 'GET',
        transformResponse: function (data) {
          if (data) {
            data = angular.fromJson(data);
          }
          return data;
        },
      },
      update: { method: 'PUT' },
    }
  );
}
```